# Postman mock server for requests with dynamic request headers/body

Tags: java, rest, api, web-services, postman

I am using Postman mock server to create a mock endpoint where I need the response of the request to contain the request parameter as well as few other key values.

For example if my endpoint is /test?id=123 then i need the response as

```
    {
        "id":"123",
        "name":"anyRandomName"
    }
```

Similarly, when I hit /test?id=234 then the response should be

```
{
    "id":"234",
    "name":"anyRandomName2"
}
```

One way to achieve this is by making 2 endpoints with specific query parameters, in this example **/test?id=123** and **/test?id=234**. 
But i am looking for a way where i can read the request parameter just like **{{$id}}** or something like this. Postman do provide keywords like **{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}** which returns random strings but this will change in every hit.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am looking something like for my post request. Different input should give different outputs, but the API is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the example name in headers while making a call to the mock API with key "x-mock-response-name". this will return the example set with that name.